# System of two ODEs, problem with finding eigenvectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am fairly new to systems of ODEs so bear with me.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x' = 2x-y \\ 
y' = x+2y \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So, I know I have to find the eigenvalues, which is not a problem for me. The eigenvalues are $2 \pm i$

After inserting the first value in the matrix of the system and multiplying it by a column-matrix consisting of $C_1$ and $C_2$, I get the system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-iC_1 - C_2 = 0\\ 
C_1-iC_2=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Now, my question is as follows:

If I express $C_2$ from the first equation I get $C_2 = -i C_1$. After inserting that in the second equation I get that $C_1 - C_1 = 0$, which leads me to think that $C_1$ is any real number. After choosing the number $1$, I get that the *eigenvector* is $v_1 = (1,-i)$

However, WolframAlpha says that the eigenvector is $(i,1)$, which leads me to think that I should have expressed $C_1$ from the second equation and substituted it into the first, which is when I get the same solution as in WolframAlpha.

But does it matter what variable I express though? I'm also new to eigenvectors so I don't know a whole lot about them. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector, multiplying $v$ by a non-zero scalar, results in an eigenvector. What do you get when you multiply the eigenvector _you_ found with $i$?

Comment: @GitGud I get the eigenvector they provided. So does it mean that my eigenvector can also be used to solve the system, even if WolframAlpha hasn't provided it as a possible eigenvector?

Comment: Any eigenvector will do. Try it yourself with what you found and what WolframAlpha gave you. See where it leads you.

Answer (score 1):

Writing
\begin{align}
-iC_1 - C_2 &= 0 \\
C_1-iC_2 &=0
\end{align}

And multiplying the first relationship by $i$ one finds
\begin{align}
-C_1 +i C_2 &= 0\\ 
C_1-iC_2 &=0
\end{align}
Whereby one relationship is a factor of $-1$ of the other. Do you see where I am heading?

Comment: well I'd guess that it means that there are infinitely many solutions to the system, if I'm not mistaken, though I don't know much else!